# handling json requests and responses in scala play framework and send to angular js java script

Tags: json, scala, angularjs, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am working on implementation of library system using play framework and angularjs.
suppose to search for a book in the library the user enters the keyword value in the input field, this value is received by the controller from the GET request. I need to search the MySQL database for the list of the books, convert them to json request and display them back in the search page which is implemented using angularjs. 
I don't understand how to use json and send the result back to the web page.

```
GET     /books/all/search/:by/:value  controllers.Books.listBooks(by: String, value: String)



case class Book (
 bookId: String,
 title: String,
 author: String,
 category:String,
 price: Int,
 location: String,
 status: String
)

object Book{
   val bookParse = {
     get[String]("book.bookId") ~
     get[String]("book.title") ~
     get[String]("book.author") ~
     get[String]("book.category") ~
     get[Int]("book.price") ~
     get[String]("book.location") ~
     get[String]("book.status")map {
     case bookId~title~author~category~price~location~status => Book(bookId,title, author, category, price, location, status)
     }
  }


def searchByBookId(bookId: String) : List[Book]= {
  DB.withConnection {implicit connection =>
  SQL("select * from book where bookId = {bookId}").as(Book.bookParse *)
 }
}



object Books extends Controller {
 def listBooks(by: String, value:String): List[Book] =
 {
  if (by == "byBookId" )  Book.searchByBookId(value)
  else if(by == "byTitle")Book.searchByTitle(value)
  else Book.searchByAuthor(value)
 }
}
```

Now i need to send the List[Book] result to the web page

Answer (score 2):

```
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val bookFormat = Json.format[Book]

def listBooks(by: String, value: String) = Action {
  val books = if (by == "byBookId" ) Book.searchByBookId(value)
    else if(by == "byTitle")Book.searchByTitle(value)
    else Book.searchByAuthor(value)
  Ok(Json.toJson(books))
}
```

The `implicit val bookFormat` needs to be either on the Book companion object, or in scope when `Json.toJson` is called.

More documentation on JSON:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson